# Springboot digest authentication support

Tags: spring-boot

I need to implement HTTP digest authentication for my Springboot Application. I have tried configuring this from Tomcat setup ([How to use digest authentication in Tomcat 8.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967289/how-to-use-digest-authentication-in-tomcat-8-5).B) ut since Springboot doesn't generate any web.xml, I couldn't configure this. Can someone, please, give a piece of advice as for is there any alternative?

Steps Followed

```
1.generated sha -256 password 

   digest.bat -s 0 -a sha-256 tomcat

2. updated tomcat user file


        <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
        <user username="tomcat"         password="ce066452368a3498047a43323cff46a00222945691d728747a2283273506a0a7" 
        roles="manager-gui,manager,admin"></user>

3. updated tomcat conf/server.xml

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
            <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-256" /> 
        </Realm>
    </Realm>

4. updated tomcat conf/web.xml

    <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>MySecureResource</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin-gui</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <security-role>
        <role-name>admin-gui</role-name>
      </security-role>
      <login-config>
            <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
            <realm-name>UserDatabase</realm-name>
        </login-config>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far so we can help you!

Comment: Just use Spring security for that... Add the `DigestAuthenticationFilter` to the security chain.

Comment: Ty @M.Deinum : I have started looking in Spring Security Class .

Comment: @DAA added the steps , I have followed