# How to get Tomcat CredentialHandler inside Java when nested in LockoutRealm

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.59 and have the following Realm in my context.xml:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/MyName" localDataSource="true">
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
      </CredentialHandler>
    </Realm>
</Realm>
```

I would like to get the CredentialHandler in my Java app to hash and store passwords.  As per Christopher Schultz's presentation at [http://people.apache.org/~schultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202016/Seamless%20Upgrades%20for%20Credential%20Security%20in%20Apache%20Tomcat.pdf](http://people.apache.org/%7Eschultz/ApacheCon%20NA%202016/Seamless%20Upgrades%20for%20Credential%20Security%20in%20Apache%20Tomcat.pdf) I get it like this:

```java
CredentialHandler ch = (CredentialHandler) application.getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER);
```

The problem is that it returns a blank/default credential handler, not the one I have configured.

If I remove the LockoutRealm definition, it works fine, so it seems that having a nested realm (LockoutRealm, DataSourceRealm), causes it to fail.  Looking through the Tomcat code, it seems that the code that calls `setAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER)` doesn't take `CombinedRealm` into account.

How can I get the configured credential handler in my app so that I can call the .matches() and .mutate() methods?
I would rather not remove the Lockout Realm because that would compromise security.

---

Edit:

This use-case is a common one: The application must be able to save the mutated password to the database so that tomcat can do form-based authentication against it when users log in.  Every time a new user account is created, the user's password must be mutated and saved to the database.

Additionally, when a user wants to change their password, a form would ask for the current and new passwords - .matches() is used to confirm that the "current" password matches their existing password before changing it to the new password (which again must be mutated).

Using the credential handler defined in the context is important to ensure the password is mutated in the exact way that tomcat requires.  The alternative would be for every application to provide their own corresponding libraries, which seems wasteful and error-prone given that tomcat already has them.

This is all described in Christopher Schultz's link at the start of my question.

I think this is all pretty standard and Tomcat provides `CredentialHandler ch = (CredentialHandler) application.getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER)` for this purpose.  The issue is that the implementation doesn't account for LockoutRealm being used - it assumes that the credential handler is defined directly under the top-level realm, so I'm wondering if it's an oversight/bug in tomcat or if it works like that by design and if there's some way I can access the .mutate() and .matches() functions of the defined `CredentialHandler` while also using the `LockOutRealm`.

Also, tomcat used to provide `RealmBase.Digest(String credentials, String algorithm, String encoding)` for this use-case, but that method is deprecated in 8.5 and removed in 9, so I understand `CredentialHandler ch = (CredentialHandler) application.getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER)` is the new way we're supposed to be doing it.

---

Edit 2:

`getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER)` returns a default `CredentialHandler` that doesn't encrypt the password at all. The debugger shows the class being `StandardContext`. Stepping through the code, that all seems correct, but it doesn't drill into the `DataSourceRealm` to get the defined `NestedCredentialHandler`, instead, it looks at `LockoutRealm`, doesn't find an immediate child `CredentialHandler`, so creates and returns a default one. I believe this is as documented in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/credentialhandler.html:

> A CredentialHandler element MUST be nested inside a Realm component. If it is not included, a default CredentialHandler will be created using the MessageDigestCredentialHandler.

Comment: What's wrong with https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.html#getCredentialHandler()?

Comment: @Michael-O How would I get the Realm first?

Comment: Tomcat internal structures are not intented to be consumed by the application. If you need to process passwords yourself then you don't need container-managed security.

Comment: @Michael-O So how is one supposed to hash a password from a user to store it in the database in the first place? How about when the user changes their password?

Comment: @Michael-O Thanks for your comments. Just to be clear, I asked about accessing the Realm in response to your original question "What's wrong with [RealmBase.getCredentialHandler]". If I can't/not supposed to have access to it (as per your subsequent comment), then I think that answers your question. As for "processing password" myself - this is a normal use-case - my question is whether I'm going about it the correct way using Tomcat.

Comment: @Edward, what are you getting from getAttribute, is it null

Comment: @Ironluca It returns a valid (default) credential handler that doesn't mutate the password at all, i.e. the password is returned as plaintext - certainly not the CH that's defined. I added Edit 2 to my question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Please check,  added the answer back after modification, now that the problem is clear.

Comment: @Michael-O This feature of Tomcat is *specifically designed* to allow applications to interact with the password-mutation scheme actively being used by Tomcat.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz then the application isn't container agnostic. This should be clear then.

Comment: @Michael-O True, it's no longer container-agnostic. But unless you want to go through the pain of using reflection to call the mutator method in the CredentialHandler, you're going to have to compile against Tomcat's classes, anyway, at which point it should be clear that Tomcat would be required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you need to configure an identical (or operationally identical) `CredentialHandler` on the LockOutRealm.

(I'm sorry I didn't see this question 2 years ago!)

Since you don't ever intend to create *new* passwords using `SHA-512` (you expect to always write new credentials that are using PBKDF2, right?), you can do this:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/MyName" localDataSource="true">
      <!--
        Define a CredentialHandler which will be used
        exclusively by the container. See below for one that
        can be used by the application.

        This repeated-configuration is necessary because of the
        use of the LockOutRealm, which hides the CredentialHandler
        defined on the "real realm" from its parent.
      -->
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
      </CredentialHandler>
    </Realm>
    <!--
      Repeat the NestedCredentialHandler for the benefit of the
      LockOutRealm, which would otherwise have an empty/default
      CredentialHandler whish is not useful to the application.

      This allows the application to obtain a CredentialHandler
      which can be used to both verify existing user credentials
      as well as generate new stored-credentials.

      This must be a copy of the NestedCredentialHandler above,
      in order to both allow verification of existing user
      credentials (using #matches(), which will try all possible
      nested CredentialHandlers) as well as the generation of
      new stored credentials (using #mutate(), which will only
      use the first-defined aka primary CredentialHandler.
      -->
    <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
    </CredentialHandler>
</Realm>
```

The innermost `CredentialHandler` will be used during login to actually check that your credentials match, while the outermost `CredentialHandler` will be used when you want to mutate your own from within your application.

Comment: Will this handle the change password use-case where they're already logged in, but need to enter their current password again? The server then needs to verify that it matches what's in the database, which could be either SHA-512 or PBKDF2.

Comment: To answer your question: new passwords will always be in PBKDF2, but checking the old password (before allowing a change password) could be in either PBKDF2 or SHA-512

Comment: @Edward The `NestedCredentialHandler` will always check all of the handlers and will only return `false` (i.e. unauthorized) if none of the nested concrete `CredentialHandlers` return true. This is identical to the use-case where the user is logging-in.

Comment: This doesn't work - `matches` needs to include `SHA-512`. The full `NestedCredentialHandler` needs to be replicated for this to work correctly. It won't let me remove the -1 until you edit your answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, I understand exactly what you are saying, here, @Edward. I was thinking that the container was performing the password verification (which would used the nested one) but you were asking about the application performing that password-verification itself (which is reasonable, as changing a user's password really ought to double-check the current password as a part of that process!)

Answer (score 0):

Now that the use cases are clear. What you mention in your edits is correct. It starts with the [RealmBase](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/6053839acc97b4f3eb9f286c5633d0c1dc2e9c09/java/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.java) class (refer: protected void startInternal() method). This, if teh credential handler is null (which in your case it is on LockoutRealm), sets the default credential handler as MessageDigestCredentialHandler without any algorithm, the behaviour of the credential handler if no algorithm is specified is to use plainText.

Next look at the [StandardContext](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/99647b373c41e1ee1424665a1ccf2174848aa176/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java) (refer: protected synchronized void startInternal() method, line 5016-5027), lines 5019 and 5024 are important. Here the realm is being retrieved with the 'getRealmInternal()' call, which returns the configured realm, which in your case is LockoutRealm and the subsequent 'getCredentialHandler()' returns the default credential handler as mentioned above (as the method is dispatched to RealmBase, ***a point to be noted, the CombinedRealm or the LockoutRealm does not override this method***).

This is why the password is not being mutated.

What you require looks to be possible. It is apparent from the above that when the 'getCredentialHandler()' is called on the realm, the realm should handle it instead of dispatching to RealmBase.

Therefore, you could do the below:

1. Extend LockoutRealm with your realm class (say XRealm)
2. Override the getCredentialHandler method
3. In the method, access the 'protected final List realms' of CombinedRealm, your DataSourceRealm should be the 0th element
4. Call the getCredentialHandler on the DataSourceRealm and return
5. When StandardContext calls getCredentialHandler, it should get the NestedCredentialHandler you have configured

The above should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question to explain the use-case - hope that makes it clear.  I don't need direct access to the CredentialHandler. Tomcat already returns an indirect interface that provides access to the mutate() and matches() methods, which is fine, just that it doesn't work with LockoutRealm

Comment: Yes, I think that would work, though I'd rather remove the LockoutRealm altogether than implement my own. I think this should be considered a bug in tomcat. Your previous version of this answer was better for me where you suggested I use SecretKeyCredentialHandler directly. I'll accept this either way because I think it's about as close as we can get to a solution. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Edward, you could extend the LockoutRealm, it is fairly straight forward. However, using the credential handler class directly is an uncomplicated solution. However, one suggestion is that you dont remove the LockoutRealm as it provides functionality which is important (actually account lockout is a control that is tested during penetration testing of applications). As for it being a bug, I am not quite sure if it is, for instance if there are more than one realm configured inside combined realm, which realm's credential handler should be considered by getCredentialHandler. Perhaps by design

Comment: Agreed, better to leave the LockoutRealm in there.  For a CombinedRealm with multiple CHs, better default behaviour would be to at least return the first CH it finds rather than a default/blank one without searching. LockoutRealm is a fairly common use-case and I think that getAttribute(Globals.CREDENTIAL_HANDLER) should make some attempt at working with it. That's why this seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and was only able to login when I input the DIGEST created for some specific credential handler into the browser's dialog. So really the value stored in `tomcat-users.xml`. That made me believe that always only the hard-coded default credential handler allowing plain-text passwords only assigned to `LockOutRealm` is used and my other handler assigned to the child realm ignored.

BUT that wasn't the case! I was forced to double-check my config after speaking about this problem on the [Tomcat mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread/q25tg6t2cyovyymz5bhl069g508s2m8j) and recognized that for [other reasons](https://lists.apache.org/thread/y7l85kzoppx4ztyhogl1vsmm4hht9l31) my `auth-method` configured in `web.xml` was still set to `DIGEST` instead of `BASIC`. `DIGEST` and a really digested password in `tomcat-users.xml` can't work together and therefore I was able to provide that digest when the browser asked for my password to successfully login. Therefore I thought that the hard-coded default credential helper assigned to `LockOutRealm` is used always and only, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

My setup was pretty similar to yours:

```xml
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
    <CredentialHandler  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler"
                        algorithm="PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512"
                        iterations="100000"
                        keyLength="256"
                        saltLength="16"
    />
  </Realm>
</Realm>
```

So, if anyone comes across the same issue, double-check your config for `BASIC` vs. `DIGEST`, that really the correct value is stored in `tomcat-users.xml`, provided to the browser and stuff like that. There are multiple other people reporting a setup like mine above working as well and currently it seems those are right! ;-)

I guess that the hard-coded credential handler for `LockOutRealm` is simply chosen because it doesn't really handle logins at all. It most likely only needs to prevent timing attacks and stuff, read something like that in the bugtracker. Though, actual logins are forwarded the child realms and it seems that credential handlers assigned to them are properly handled by them.

So regarding original question, one should start with NOT using `NestedCredentialHandler`, but ONLY `SecretKeyCredentialHandler` and get that successfully working. Afterwards `NestedCredentialHandler` could be tried, but if any problems persists, this most likely have to do with `NestedCredentialHandler` instead of `LockOutRealm` or more likely with things like `BASIC` vs. `DIGEST` and stuff.

Comment: This may be somewhat related, but it does not answer the original question at all, which was about using `CredentialHandlers` from within the application itself. The original question wasn't about not being able to login, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replicating the Credential Handler in my code:

```java
private CredentialHandler getCredentialHandler() {
  NestedCredentialHandler ch1 = new NestedCredentialHandler();
  ch1.addCredentialHandler(new SecretKeyCredentialHandler());

  MessageDigestCredentialHandler md = new MessageDigestCredentialHandler();
  md.setAlgorithm("SHA-512");
  ch1.addCredentialHandler(md);

  return ch1;
}
```

It is then possible to call `matches()`, which will match on either algorithm, and also call `mutate()`, which will use the first listed algorithm.

As mentioned by @christopher-schultz, replicating the `NestedCredentialHandler` in the `LockOutRealm` will also work:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" >
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" dataSourceName="jdbc/MyName" localDataSource="true">
      <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
      </CredentialHandler>
    </Realm>
    <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.NestedCredentialHandler">
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.SecretKeyCredentialHandler" />
        <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-512" />
    </CredentialHandler>
</Realm>
```