# Trying to log in to Tomcat Manager using encrypted password generated using digest.bat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, digest-authentication

I've my `tomcat-users.xml` defined this way on Windows 11, tomcat version 9.0.78:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="jack" password="4f60ef32b9f4cf8a30d85167c9575e627d1f03845575a620ff5654b85eb29add$1$15a54860775edfab43b7010aed9ca814c6647f5b1c07253cbcdac7dc80e07833ee9ae5392aac0b7ba96760100a1462dcc51ed91cb8c4768bba1de77193f0ad57" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
  <user username="TomcatJackAdmin" password="test" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

And I've generated the hash like this from my bin directory :

```
bin>.\digest.bat -a SHA-512 -h org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler password
```

When I login to Tomcat Manager (tomcat 9.0.78) on Windows using `TomcatJackAdmin` and `test`, it works fine. But I'm trying to use the encrypted stuff, username- `jack` and the `password` for which hash exists above. It doesn't work. Are there an additional steps I need to fix the above issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use digest authentication in Tomcat 8.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967289/how-to-use-digest-authentication-in-tomcat-8-5)

Comment: That doesn't. I looked at it before asking. They are also suggesting to make changes in `web.xml` but for one user, I have this thing working without any changes in `web.xml` so that's confusing.  Also, it's not very clear how to test the web.xml part in the answer.

Comment: I stand by  my duplicate suggestion. Especially point 3 (digest sha512) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572112/13447) is critical

Answer (score 0):

- generated the hash like this from bin directory:

> digest.bat -a sha-256 admin

Change the password with the hash in tomcat-users.xml
Add in server.xml:

```
<CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-256" />
```

as a result :

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase">
     <CredentialHandler className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler" algorithm="SHA-256" />
</Realm>
```